# Passing byte string from Python to C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-extensions

I am writing a python extension in C and I am trying to pass a bytes object to my function.  Obviously the 's' token is for strings; I have tried 'O', 'N', and a few others with no luck. Is there a token I can use to parse a bytes object? If not is there an alternative method to parse bytes objects?

```
static PyObject *test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *dev;
    uint8_t *key;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ss", &dev, &key))
        return NULL;

    printf("%s\n", dev);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
          printf("Val %d: %d\n", i, key[i]);
    }

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Calling from python: `test(b"device", f.read(32))`.

Comment: If you use Python 3, the first argument in the call of your *test* function is an unicode string, not a bytes string. You need to write `b"device"` instead.

Comment: No, the first arg is supposed to be a Unicode string containing the device name. The second arg is a crypto key read in from a file as a bytes object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [parsing format string docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers), it's pretty clear.

`s` is solely for getting a `NUL` terminated UTF-8 encoded C-style string from a `str` object (so it's appropriate for your first argument, but not your second).

`y*` is specifically called out in the docs with (emphasized in original text):

> **This is the recommended way to accept binary data.**

`y#` would also work, at the expense of requiring the caller to provide immutable `bytes`-like objects, excluding stuff like `bytearray` and `mmap.mmap`s.

Comment: Firstly, this answered my question; however, it terminates after the loop with `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`. Any quick reason you see why this is?

Comment: @DanielCopley: *After* the loop? Your code as written could conceivably seg fault if you read outside the bounds of the input array, but it's unlikely. I have no idea what changed once you used buffers though; you're basically asking for psychic debugging here. Segfaults mean you tried to read or write to addresses that aren't mapped into your memory space, but it doesn't say much else.

Comment: I think I am possibly using the `Py_buffer` type incorrectly? I switched `y*` to  `y` (which returns a character pointer instead of `Py_buffer`) and this seems to have resolved my issue. Not sure if there are any pitfalls with this approach.

Comment: @DanielCopley: Raw binary data is apt to contain `NUL` bytes. If you don't use `y*` or `y#`, you have no idea what the real length of the data is, and may stop before you reach the end.

Comment: The data is an encryption key and will always be 256bits. If I positively know the length, is there any other issues with using `y`?

Comment: @DanielCopley: The fact that "positively knowing the length" and getting it wrong means you segfault, or produce total gibberish, rather than being able to raise a helpful exception is a problem. The instant you rely on caller data, you shouldn't be writing code that makes assumptions that can crash your program with no useful diagnostics. It's also misleading to maintainers, who can and will reasonably assume `y` means "`NUL`-terminated byte string", because that's the only legal use of it.